# Node JS Twitter Module - exceeded connection limit for user

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter

I'm building a node app where users can select keywords to follow on Twitter. Their 'wall' will be automatically updated as new tweets come in with their selected keywords.

The way I've built it is each user joins their own room named with their user id. The tweets should then be pushed to their room and prepended to the list with jQuery.

The problem is If I open 4 tabs and log 4 different users in it only updates the first 2 that were logged in with their Twitter feed! It doesn't matter which order I log them in it's only the first to that receive updates.

When logging the error I get: Exceeded connection limit for the user

I'm guessing Twitter only allows a single connection per API account. Is this correct?

Is there any way around this as I need individual streams for each user?

My server code is:

```
var socket  = require( './public/node_modules/socket.io' );
var express = require('./public/node_modules/express');
var request = require('./public/node_modules/request');
var Twitter = require('./public/node_modules/twitter');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 4321;

 server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

//setup Twitter Details
var watchList = ['ferrari'];
var T = new Twitter({
   consumer_key:         'xxx'
  , consumer_secret:      'xxx'
  , access_token_key:     'xxx'
  , access_token_secret:  'xxx'
});

io.on('connection', function (client) {


client.on('join', function(data)
  {


//send to the user in question i.e client
client.emit('update','You are connected');

//send to ALL users
io.sockets.emit('update', 'New user '+data.name+' has joined');


client.join(data.id, function()
{
  console.log('JOINING ROOM: '+data.id+' following: '+data.following);

   if(data.following!='')
      {



        T.stream('statuses/filter', {track: data.following}, function(stream) {
          stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
            client.emit('stream',tweet.text);              
          //io.sockets.to(data.id).emit('stream', tweet.text);
          });
         
          stream.on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
        });

      }  
   }); 

  });


});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are going to let more than one user to see their data related with their twitter account you need to use Oauth rathen than a Twitter Developer Account.